# JavaFx Displaying Images from pixel array

Tags: image, javafx, pixel

I changed pixel array of an image, and I want to display it.
I tried this code (below), but it's doesn't work.

```
int[] pixelSrcImage;
PixelGrabber pgSrc = 
new PixelGrabber(imageSrc, 0, 0, imageHeight, imageWidth, pixelSrcImage, 0,imageWidth);
pgSrc.grabPixels();

pixelSrcImage[...]=...

PixelWriter pw = null;
WritablePixelFormat<IntBuffer> format = WritablePixelFormat.getIntArgbInstance();
pw.setPixels(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight,   format, step, 0, imageWidth);
Image imView = new Image (pw.???);
```

Comment: That's not compilable code.  Edit your question to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain what "doesn't work" means (e.g. include the full stack trace of the error you receive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the destination image first and not set the PixelWriter to null.

```
WritableImage image = new WritableImage(width, height);
PixelWriter pw = image.getPixelWriter();
```

All I can see from your bits & pieces is that you'll get a NullPointer Exception.

And please consider what jewelsea said.